# Voltage divider for multiple gpio inputs

Tags: gpio, electronics, voltage

I have a system that can output 12V depending on measured events.
The way the 12V of the system are provided is via a 12V output that gets shorted to GND via a transistor output.

I wanted to use these outputs to program inputs on my Raspberry, so I build 3 equal voltage dividers, for 3 inputs.

Everything worked fine until I connected all 3 up and noticed that if one transistor output shorts to ground, all 3 of them short to ground and thus all 3 of my GPIO inputs go to HIGH at once.

My circuit basically looks like this:[image: Voltage divider with attached circuits]

What would I have to change in order to have them work independently? I am quite new to electronics so I dont know too much

Comment: It is unclear what you have done or are asking. The rather vague picture seems unrelated to the question. **DO NOT** post pictures use the schematic tool.

Comment: Your schematic omits an essential element: What does the *output stage* of your 12V system look like? It ***sounds like*** you're describing a *pullup* to a 12V supply, that is *pulled down* by the transistor you've mentioned. This is *likely* an easy problem to solve, but we need a complete schematic for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear to me. Let's first try to define the problem clearly; the answer should fall out easily after that. Below is a schematic (created using [RPi SE's invaluable tool](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/how-do-i-add-a-schematic-to-my-question/2075#2075)). From the description in your question, I *imagine* this is how it is designed:

*Three **independent** binary outputs that switch between 12VDC and GROUND. Note the presence of a **pullup resistor** (R1, R2, R3) on each channel. When the transistor (Q1, Q2 or Q3) is turned OFF, and **with nothing connected** to the output (Node1, Node2 or Node3) a voltmeter will read 12VDC.*

[image: external system schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxofHA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You will need to ***verify*** whether the above schematic is accurate - or not. This may be accomplished simply if you have a voltmeter (use LEDs otherwise):

1. Remove all connections from the outputs (Node1, Node2 & Node3).
2. Measure the voltage between Node1 and GND; repeat for Node2 & Node3
3. *ADJUST* the **input** to your system, and repeat Step 2

##### Case I

If the voltages at Nodes1-3 are **never** different from each other, your external system's outputs are not independent, and there's nothing you can do with the RPi to make them behave differently.

##### Case II

If the voltages at Nodes1-3 **are** different from each other, and dependent upon the external system's inputs, you have mis-wired something, and the schematic you've provided is either incorrect or incomplete.

Having sorted that, your next step is to design a proper interface *between* the RPi GPIO pins; **proper** being an interface that provides [*approximately*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/136216/83790) 3.3V output when the external system's output (Node1, 2 or 3) is 12V, and [*approximately*](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/136216/83790) 0V (relative to GND).

The *voltage divider* interface you've adopted in your schematic is only one (of many) possible interfaces. Some [alternatives to the voltage divider are listed in another answer here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/136197/83790), and may be useful in your case. The primary issue in designing a **proper** interface to an external system that uses a pullup resistor is that some of the interfaces require you to account for the **pullup resistor's value** in design of the interface. Consider the use of a Zener diode interface to simplify that design.